# How can I offer event registration cancellation but not registration transfer?

Tags: civievent

I want to allow participants to cancel a registration but not to transfer it to someone else. It seems that CiviEvent offers either both or neither. Is there a way of just enabling one?

Answer (score 3):

You need the [self-service cancel only](https://lab.civicrm.org/extensions/selfsvcnoxfer) extension.